# Typescript server side no errors for using Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Currently I'm converting my Javascript project to Typescript. When I did the front end I used to get errors which helped a lot to convert it to typescript.  For the back end I'm not getting any errors even though it's not in typescript. Could someone please help me with this one code block, it would help to get me a good start! My current IDE is Webstorm.

```
const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    let token = req.headers["authorization"];

    if (!token) {
       return res.status(403).send({
            message: "No token provided"
        });
    }

    jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(401).send({
                message: "Unauthorized"
            });
        }
        req.userId = decoded.id;
        next();
    });

};
```

tsconfig.json

```
   {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the code in a `.ts` file? What does your `tsconfig.json` file look like?

Comment: Yes its in a .ts file.